# Symfony2 file download cutoff from Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, download

I have written a Symfony2(PHP MVC Framework) script to download a zip file from the server. But the file download stops in the midway. I have increased the max_execution_time in apache configuration. Still the problem is persisting.

Do anyone have the quick fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This smells like an issue with a browser? Which one do you use?

Comment: how big is the file?  I've had issues like this with a big file, and all you need to do is allow streaming downloads.  Also, if you show a bit of your code, it will make it much easier to see the problem

Comment: Hi Guys Please check this URL for the code script written to download the file : http://pastebin.com/WS6vjWyQ

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have an issue with a large file (downloading an archive of videos).  You should use a [StreamedResponse](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#streaming-a-response).  This way, you don't have to store the entire contents of your file in memory, it will just stream to the client.  The way you are currently doing it makes the file load into memory before it can start to download.  You can see why this could be a problem.  Here is a simple example of how you can stream a file to the client:

```
$path = "//usr/www/users/jjdqlo/Wellness/web/yoga_videos/archive.zip";

return new StreamedResponse(
        function () use ($path) {  // first param is a callback, where you do the readfile()
            readfile($path);
        }, 
        200,  // second param is the http status code
        array(  // third param is an array of header settings
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename="archive.zip"',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/zip'
        )
);
```

Give this a shot.  Assuming the problem is because of file size, this should solve the issue.

Comment: THanks Sehael. I would try your suggestion

Comment: actually the download is stopping roughly around 7-8 minutes after the download has begun. The max_execution_time limit is also increased what could be exact issue here?

Comment: I got the below transcript in the log file for my task but i dont see any bug in it.


http://pastebin.com/Luu2zJ8a

Could you clarify if the bug is from the server end or not?

Comment: the error would be in either the apache or php logs, not the symfony logs